# How to explain telegraf high cardinality?

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, cardinality

I need you help regarding to Telegraf monitoring of influxDB instance and a behavior I cannot explain.

The configuration is the following:

- Two independent instances of InfluxDB v1.7.10 are running on seperate servers, say *server A* and *server B*
- Two telegraf services v1.13.4 are running with the same configuration:

  - One output being a "monitoring" database created in the influx database
  - Several inputs (system, disk, ping, ...)
- Grafana is used on both server to explore Telegraf stored values

**On server A, which is running fine, the monitoring shard size and cardinality are quite regular. On server B on the other hand, the monitoring shard size and cardinality are much more important (by a factor 10).**

I cannot explain this difference and I have already checked:

- tag and field cardinality of the inputs used on both server
- telegraf configuration on both server

**Any idea about where to look to explain this behavior ?**

Tanks for your help !